# Changing spacing between top sides of nested composites in SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

Is it possible to change the spacing between the top sides of two nested Composites in SWT?

For example, when using the code below I get the result shown here:

[image]

I would like there not to be any space between the top sides of the red and the blue composites, as shown here:

[image]

I tried making the height of the two components the same (using `GridData`), but that didn't work.

```
public class CompositeSnippet
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Composite c1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    GridData c1GridData = new GridData(100, 50);
    c1.setLayoutData(c1GridData);
    c1.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    c1.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));


    Composite c2 = new Composite(c1, SWT.NONE);
    GridData c2GridData = new GridData(50, 50);
    c2.setLayoutData(c2GridData);
    c2.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

}

Based on this article on [layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html), it seems that this spacing might be due to the trim of the blue composite. I tried to create my own custom widget that extends Composite and overrides the `computeTrim(...)` method, but that didn't work either...

P.S. It seems that this question must have been already asked, but I could not find anything on *stackoverflow* related to it. If this has already been addressed, please point me to the right discussion and I apologize for the duplicate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Composite outer = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    outer.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    outer.setLayout(layout);
    outer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Composite inner = new Composite(outer, SWT.NONE);
    inner.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
    inner.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    inner.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Just use `GridLayout#marginHeight` and set it to `0`.

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `GridLayout.marginHeight` of composite c1 to 0.

```
public class CompositeSnippet
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Composite c1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    GridData c1GridData = new GridData(100, 50);
    c1.setLayoutData(c1GridData);

    //Set marginWidth and marginHeight of parent composite to 0
    GridLayout c1Layout = new GridLayout();
    c1Layout.marginHeight = 0;
    c1.setLayout(c1Layout);
    c1.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));

    Composite c2 = new Composite(c1, SWT.NONE);
    GridData c2GridData = new GridData(50, 50);
    c2.setLayoutData(c2GridData);
    c2.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. I accepted Baz's answer above because it also adds some coding style improvements to the original code snippet.